# Are there other undocumented paths apart from timeline and reputation audit?

Tags: support, timeline, reputation-audit, hidden-features

I'm aware of these *interesting* (relative) paths that can be used on any SE site:

- The **timeline of a post**, such as [this example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/294552/timeline). It has a relative path like `/posts/postid/timeline` (similar to the path of the revision history of a post, in which the `revisions`-part of it is changed to `timeline`).
- The **reputation audit on a site**, such as [this example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/reputation). It has a relative path like `/reputation`.

To my knowledge:

- nowhere in the help pages these relative paths are documented.
- there is not even 1 page on any SE site that have a link to any of these relative paths.

I only discovered these (what I call) *undocumented* relative paths by accident, after I saw them mentioned in some post.

Question: are there any other *undocumented* relative paths, and available to anybody (so not just mods or so)? If so which ones, and what is their purpose?